# can anyone explain the accuracy measurements in forecasting package on R?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting

am new to data science.i have used forecast package in R and got some accuracy measurements like RMSE,ME,MAPE etc.

can anyone explain me this measurements in a practical approach?

Please see my example code.

```
> library(forecast)

> data=read.csv("experiment.csv")
> head(data)
  BATCH value value1 value2
1     I     5.77  21.32   34.82
2    II     4.46  20.36   46.89
3   III     4.57  22.64   42.95
4    IV     3.54  23.63   48.45
5     V     6.34  19.33   36.43
6    VI     4.56  25.36   39.58

> dataset=data.frame(value=data$value,value1=data$value1,value2=data$value2)
> fit.nn=nnetar(dataset$value)
> modelaccuracy.nn=accuracy(fit.nn)
> modelaccuracy.nn
                         ME             RMSE            MAE             MPE             MAPE        MASE        ACF1   
Training set 0.001978004     0.4052840794   0.3743702393    -0.9462031738   9.191369199 0.3249114902    -0.2064674413
```

here some measurements has negative values.what it actually means?whether it's a bad dataset or forecasting accuracy would be not good?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a question about programming so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. If you have questions about interpreting values from statistical models, you should as your question at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Comment: Read this "2.5 Evaluating forecast accuracy" https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5

Comment: Thanks MrFlick i will post this question on cross validated.

Comment: This question has been asked here before, you could try finding it. Or just look at the free online forecasting textbook "Forecasting: principles and practice" by Hyndman & Athanasopoulos, they explain all these measures [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5).